# Volume rocker as next/previous song

Tags: 2.3-gingerbread, music-player, buttons, volume-control

This probably is a common question but so far I have not seen a thorough answer.

I want to know if it is possible to have the rocker functionalities that are on cyanogem mod on a factory rom (htc desire s).
that is:

long press up    =  next song.

long press down  =  previous song.

short press up   =  volume up

short press down =  volume down

I would like to keep using the HTC ROM, since I like the sense UI, and also id like to keep using the HTC music player, I think is simple and is able to manage correctly the compilations albums.

Does anyone know of an app that can do this, that is NOT another music player.
Or as a 2nd option to explain if it is possible to create my own app for it and maybe to make some points towards the right direction to do this.